# Taking a git branch from one repo into another repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have 2 repos: `repoA` and `repoB`.

`repoA` contains scripts that are required by project under `repoB`.

I created a branch under `repoA` called `repoA_usedinB`.

I would like to pull `repoA_usedinB` to be under `repoB`- develop it while `repoB` project is active and then merge it back to `repoA/repoA_usedinB` for future use.

Comment: To be clear, you want a branch of repoA as a folder in repoB?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure `repoA_usedinB` is an actual branch ([`git switch -c`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)), and not a subfolder.

You could add repoA as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of repoB, with `repoA_usedinB` branch, with [`git submodule add -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt)

```
cd /path/to/repo/B
git submodule add -b repoA_usedinB /url/of/repoA
```

Any subsequent `git submodule update --remote` in `repoB` will update the repoA subfolder with the latest of that branch.
From the `repoA` subfolder, you can add, commit and push (to `repoA` in `repoA_usedinB` branch)
Don't forget to also add, commit and push in the parent repo `repoB`.